# Using SimpleJdbcCall to call a stored procedure with optional parameters is not working

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures

I have the following parameters list in my stored procedure:

```
@ContractAgreement VARCHAR(100) = '1 Month',
@val1 VARCHAR,
@val2 VARCHAR
```

I have the following SimpleJdbcCall configuration:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
    .withProcedureName(getProcedureName())
    .returningResultSet(RESULT_SET, rowMapper)
    .useInParameterNames("val1", "val2");

final MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    param.addValue("val1", "test1").addValue("val2", "test2");

jdbcCall.execute(param)
```

This results in the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'njtest' expects parameter '@val2', which was not supplied.

But if I remove the "@ContractAgreement" in parameter from the stored procedure it works fine.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Im getting the same issue, Did you find any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring SimpleJdbcCall default (optional) arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162043/spring-simplejdbccall-default-optional-arguments)